# Build Toolbar programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, toolbar

I'm learning how to use Swift, and I realized that I can't add a toolbar directly into a storyboard with a `UITableViewController`, so I'm struggling trying to add it programmatically.

This is what I'm trying to make it look like:

[image: iOS screenshot]

Now, I added this code:

```
    let homeButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "H", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ProfileButtonTapped))

    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "+", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ProfileButtonTapped))

let loveButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Love", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ProfileButtonTapped))

let arr: [Any] = [homeButton, addButton, loveButton]
setToolbarItems(arr as? [UIBarButtonItem] ?? [UIBarButtonItem](), animated: true)
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
```

And it looks like this:

[image: iOS screenshot]

But I can`t find a way to make it look with the same spacing as the original, and also If I set the image I didn't find a way to adapt the size as I need it.

I tried using this code that I found here and seemed to work, but when I load my app, it simply shows the bar without any element.

```
navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)

let homeButn = UIImage(named: "HomeButton")

let zeroPoint = CGPoint.zero
let settingsButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton
settingsButton.frame = CGRect(origin: zeroPoint, size: CGSize(width: 27, height: 27))
settingsButton.setImage(homeButn, for: [])
settingsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProfileButtonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: settingsButton)
navigationItem.setRightBarButton(rightBarButtonItem, animated: true)
```

I don't really know how to do this, any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? A tab bar within a certain view? or a tab bar for the entire app? If it's the former then I recommend a great project on git hub https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController

Comment: First, do you want to add a `UITabBar`? Or a `UIToolBar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if it helps:

```
let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

let homeButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "H", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ProfileButtonTapped))

let flexibleSpace1 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "+", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ProfileButtonTapped))

let flexibleSpace2 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

let loveButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Love", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ProfileButtonTapped))

let arr: [Any] = [flexibleSpace, homeButton, flexibleSpace1, addButton, flexibleSpace2, loveButton]

setToolbarItems(arr as? [UIBarButtonItem] ?? [UIBarButtonItem](), animated: true)

super.viewDidAppear(animated)
```

You can add flexible space on left side of 'H' too to get left space.

Comment: Need "outside" flexible spaces too:  `let arr: [Any] = [flexibleSpace1, homeButton, flexibleSpace2, addButton, flexibleSpace3, loveButton, flexibleSpace4]`

Comment: @DonMag: correct. I will update the answer. Thanks dude.

Comment: @DonMag: I don't think `flexibleSpace4` is required.

Comment: "Love" will be right-aligned without `flex4`:  `[ -- H -- + -- L -- ]`

Comment: Although, even with the flex-spacers, unless all three buttons are exactly the same widths, they won't lay out symmetrically.